# Installing TFS 08 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs

I realize that this question has been asked and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597/installing-team-foundation-server/39208#39208) but I am having problems with the slip stream approach and I'm hoping someone else has run into it. I've tried downloading the newest installation guide but the help file appears to be corrupt as it won't open any of the pages so I'm a bit in the dark here.

I rigorously followed the [TFS SP 1 slipstream installation instructions](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000444.html) but I am running into an error coded TF220059. The error explicitly states:

> TF220059: An error occurred while the Setup program was querying the installation settings for Team Foundation Server. For more information about this error, see the installation logs. For more information about the installation logs, see "Troubleshooting Installation for Team Foundation" in the Team Foundation Installation Guide.

which has me confused because as far as I can tell, no one else ran into this while slipstreaming. The results from the error log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/m296fb909). It's claiming that the accounts aren't specified but I created them as specified in [this TFS install guide](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/04/04/2512.aspx). It is a single server install so there is not a domain controller involved.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated, I've been banging my head against the desk over this. Thanks!

**EDIT:** after a bit of searching, I've found that others have ran into this problem when reporting services aren't installed. Is this required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the installation guide, try right clicking on the downloaded .chm file, click Properties and then press "Unblock".  If you then re-open the file, the content should appear.

Regarding SQL Server Reporting Services, yet it is required.  If you download the latest version of the TFS Install guide from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FF12844F-398C-4FE9-8B0D-9E84181D9923&displaylang=en

Unblock the file once downloaded, and then take a look at the section for installing SQL Server 2008 it will take you through how to get SQL set up in the way that TFS requires.  TFS needs it's pre-requisites to be installed in very particular ways (such as IIS and SQL Server), so it pays to closely follow the install guide to ensure the pre-requisites are installed as required.

Good luck.